# How to serialize and unserialize a large file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, caching, trie

I have a HUGE complex data structure (TRIE) that I need to store for later use.

So, I'm using serialize/unserialize (please suggest any better method if any):

```
$fp = fopen("serialized_trie.txt","w+");
fwrite($fp,serialize($root));
fclose($fp);

$root = unserialize(file_get_contents("serialized_trie.txt"));
```

The trie itself is made from 1 million words. So its a big trie.

I need to somehow store this trie. Writing such a big trie to file takes huge amount of time. And file_get_contents in unserialize would cause entire file to be loaded in memory.

Do I need to use a binary file instead of txt file? How?

Also I've read about 3 techniques to store:
serialize,
json_encode,
var_export

Do I need to use json_encode or var_export method in this case?

How do I QUICKLY store the trie and retrieve it?

Comment: I answered your last question and you left no feedback or comments.

Comment: @gview Just did :)

Comment: Serialize takes the variable and converts it into an intermediary form.  If you look at the file on the server, you will see that it is not hard to understand the form.  You could try to compress the file to reduce its size, but there is still going to be a significant time/cost to doing this on every request.  I provided you the standard ways of in-memory caching in the other question but you apparently rejected those for some unknown reason.  Sometimes reality dictates that you have to add complexity to achieve a performance goal.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what the actual file size is.  With that said, the serialize function basically turns the variable into an intermediary text form that can be safely written to disk, but it's not at all optimized.

You could try compressing the file before it's written:

```
$fp = fopen("serialized_trie.gzd","w+");
//gzdeflate supports 0-9 levels of compression
//You might want to experiment
fwrite($fp, gzdeflate(serialize($root), 5));
fclose($fp);
```

To read in:

```
$root = unserialize(gzinflate(file_get_contents("serialized_trie.gzd")));
```

The extension is not important, as there is no standard for raw deflate files, but I'd suggest something other than .txt to indicate this is not an actual text file.

In regards to memory use, this is highly dependent on the size of your trie structure, which you have already indicated is large, but without any specifics.

As [per my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739521/how-to-store-php-trie-for-all-later-uses/44739701?noredirect=1#comment76507707_44739701), this is going to be many times slower and than reading the variable from an in-memory cache.

Serialize is built to serialize one or more php variables and re-read those variables off disk.  It is used for php session support.

**json**

json_encode is useful if you need to return data for use in a client that needs or supports javascript compatible variables.

**var_export**

var_export has some issues with complex data structures.  With that said, it is possible to use var_export to write out the trie structure as a php script which could then be require_once().  This might be more performant than these other options.

```
$fp = fopen("trie.php","w+");
fwrite($fp, '<?php $root = ' . var_export($root) . '; ?>');
fclose($fp);
```

To read back in:

```
require_once('trie.php');
```

Obviously your script needs to place trie.php in a location under the webroot that is read/writeable, but that's a whole other discussion.  Like any other include() you need the path to the script.

Comment: The trie if written to a file, would be more than 200MB

Comment: See my expanded reply.

Comment: It also goes without saying that the writing of the trie should only be done once in a while, and the stored version used many times between updates.

Comment: Thank you! The writing of the trie is going to be only once. Please can you also tell how to read the file if I use var_export? Do I need to use include method?

Comment: Updated the answer. I'd recommend require_once, as it generates a runtime error if the script can't be found or read.

Comment: Thanks! Will test this, and let you know. Also should it be: if(file_exists('trie.php')) require_once('trie.php') else generate the file

Comment: No need to check for the file first, just require_once, and if it's not there php will throw an error.

Comment: I need to catch the error, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147645/discussion-between-gview-and-user5155835).